# How to print summation line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def squares(start, num):
    s_sum = 0
    for i in range(num):
        s_sum += start**2
        start += 1
    return s_sum
command = input("Enter a command: ")
while command == 'squares' :
    a = int(input("Enter initial integer: "))
    b = int(input("Enter the number of terms: "))
    sq_sum = squares(a, b)
    print('Sum = ', sq_sum)
```

I want to know how to print out a summation line (Ex: `Sum = 2**2 + 3**2 + 4**2 + 5**2 = 54`). My code only prints out `Sum = 54`.

Comment: use `for number in range(a, a+b)` to generate string `"number**2"`and put in list and later you can use `"+".join(list)` to concatenate this elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop to generate strings `"number**2"` and keep on list, and later you can use `' + '.join(list)` to concatename this strings

```
def squares(start, num):
    s_sum = 0
    for i in range(num):
        s_sum += start**2
        start += 1
    return s_sum

a = int(input("Enter initial integer: "))
b = int(input("Enter the number of terms: "))
sq_sum = squares(a, b)

terms = []

for number in range(a, a+b):
    terms.append("{}**2".format(number))

terms = ' + '.join(terms)

print(terms, '=', sq_sum)
```

---

**EDIT:** or shorter:

```
a = int(input("Enter initial integer: "))
b = int(input("Enter the number of terms: "))

sq_sum = sum(i**2 for i in range(a, a+b))

terms = ' + '.join("{}**2".format(i) for i in range(a, a+b))

print(terms, '=', sq_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `squares()` to return a string as well.

```
def squares(start, num):
    s_sum = 0
    output = ""
    for i in range(num):
        s_sum += start**2
        output += '{}**2+'.format(start)
        start += 1
    return s_sum, output[:-1]
```